# How to fix binding tablesorter in easytab jquery-plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, bind, tablesorter

I want to put a table (tablesorter) in every tab content with easytabs. It's only one table visible, the other ones not.

I tried to bind the tablesorter function with easytabs: before.

```
var nTab1 = 0;
var nTab2 = 0;
var nTab3 = 0;
$(function() {

  $('#tab-container1').easytabs({
    updateHash: true,
    defaultTab: "li:eq("+nTab2+")",
    active: nTab2
  })
  .bind('easytabs:before', function() {
  var $table1 = $('table#tabSort1').tablesorter({
    theme: 'blue',
    widgets: ['zebra', 'scroller', 'filter'],
    widgetOptions : {
      filter_columnFilters: false,
      filter_saveFilters : true
    }
  });

  $.tablesorter.filter.bindSearch($table1, $('#tabSearch1'));

  var $table2 = $("table#tabSort2").tablesorter({
   theme: 'blue',
   widgets: ['zebra', 'scroller', 'filter'],
   widgetOptions : {
      filter_columnFilters: false,
      filter_saveFilters : true
   }
  });

  $.tablesorter.filter.bindSearch($table2, $('#tabSearch2'));

  });

});
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Reksio/0zxmt5u2/)

Comment: Without tablesorter-function tables are visible.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Reksio/0zxmt5u2/5/)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the scroller widget sucks. It has a lot of incompatibilities, with other widgets and libraries. If you aren't going to fix a column, the I would suggest setting a max height on the tab container and using the sticky headers widget with the following changes ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/15np3r60/24/)):

HTML

```
<div class="table-wrap1">
  <table id="tabSort1" class="scroll">...</table>
</div>
...
<div class="table-wrap2">
  <table id="tabSort2" class="scroll">...</table>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.table-wrap1, .table-wrap2 {
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.tablesorter-sticky-wrapper {
  background: #fff;
}
```

JS

```
var nTab1 = 0;
var nTab2 = 0;
var nTab3 = 0;
$(function () {

  var table1 = $('table#tabSort1').tablesorter({
    theme: 'blue',
    widgets: ['zebra', 'stickyHeaders', 'filter'],
    widgetOptions: {
      filter_columnFilters: false,
      filter_saveFilters: true,
      stickyHeaders_attachTo: '.table-wrap1'
    }
  });

  $.tablesorter.filter.bindSearch(table1, $('#tabSearch1'));

  var table2 = $("table#tabSort2").tablesorter({
    theme: 'blue',
    widgets: ['zebra', 'stickyHeaders', 'filter'],
    widgetOptions: {
      filter_columnFilters: false,
      filter_saveFilters: true,
      stickyHeaders_attachTo: '.table-wrap2'
    }
  });

  $.tablesorter.filter.bindSearch(table2, $('#tabSearch2'));

  $('#tab-container1').easytabs({
    updateHash: true,
    defaultTab: "li:eq("+nTab2+")",
    active: nTab2
  });

});
```